# Security on postMessage to/from a Chrome Extension Content Script? Possible alternatives?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome-extension, postmessage, content-script

According to [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#Using_window.postMessage_in_extensions__), using postMessage to pass messages to and from a content script in chrome is not secure because can't properly define a source property, and that it's targetOrigin is difficult to securely pass to a potentially malicious site.  Is this still true.  Are there any other ways to confirm the source of a received message, and to only send messages to a specific content script exclusively?  Or are there any alternatives to using content scripts altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "chrome" in the article on MDN does not refer to "Google Chrome", but to extension code that runs with Chrome privileges ([look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome) for other meanings of "chrome" in Firefox).

In Google Chrome / Chromium, content scripts run in a [different environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) than the web page (that means that `window` in the content script is different from `window` in the web page).
However, when you send a message from the content script to the page, `event.source` will be identical to the `window` of the page. So, to verify that the message was really sent from a (content) script within the same page, you could use `if (event.source === window) { ... }`.

If you want to send a message to another content script (in the same tab), then you have two options:

1. If the frames are located at different origins, or if the content scripts are located in different tabs, then you have to send a message to the background page, which in turn passes the message to the target content script using the [Chrome extension message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) APIs.
2. If the communicating frames are located at the same origin, then their variables can directly be shared without using the message passing API. Refer to their `window` objects using `top`, `parent`, `<HTMLIFrameElement>.contentWindow`, `frames[index]`, etc.

---

Another (hackish) way to get a message from the one content script to another is through the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API. At the receiving end, bind a [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#event-onChanged) event. To "send" a message, use [`chrome.storage.local.set`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-set). Don't forget to remove the key-value pair once you have (not) received the message.